# Does the scrapy downloader reuse tcp connection?

Tags: scrapy, twisted, scrapy-splash

I have been been stuck on trying to execute an xhr request with scrapy for a lot of days now (do not feel like counting how many - because it is way too many). All my efforts end with a 400 response.

My first request, to retrieve the phpsessid returns a 200 response. (FYI it is a magento 2 website - the path of the inital request is `elasticsuite/tracker/hit/image`). The next request is the one that fails. I am guessing that the ajax call I would like to scrape is a part of the click&collect plugin from wyomind. The path is `/banner/ajax/load/?requesting_page_url=...`This request always returns a 400, no matter what. This is actually just a step to validate a cookie, before making the request of interest; `product/stores/get`

I have checked cookies and headers, as well as request sequence a lot of times now. They seem fine  , with one caveat being that the headers probably aren't in the same sort order as chrome uses when sending the request - I have not found a way to check what the Chrome sort order is. - maybe it is just alphabetical?

Today I finally gave up and decided to use splash the headless browser. To my big surprise however, splash failed to retrieve the desired info as well. The url I have been trying to request did not even show up on the network log list that splash's UI provides. I have little experience and knowledge of splash, so it is hard to speculate as to why this happens.

But the strange result gave me some new found motivation to work on the problem some more with the default scrapy downloader. One question that came to mind; Is the scrapy downloader creating a new connection for each request? I am thinking that this might be the reason the server is refusing to serve me the json I want. The cookies, and headers remain consistent accross requests, but the server might not respond as expected if the requests come in accross different tcp connections.

So, here is my question; Anyone know of whether or not the scrapy downloader, which implements the  twisted HTTPClient (`from twisted.web.http import HTTPClient`) establishes a new connection for each request, or if it reuses the tcp connection?

A follow up; Do you know of a way to inspect the connection ID during code execution?

Would really appreciate some feedback on this!

Comment: It’s probably the headers you are sending that’s the issue? What’s the url you are attempting to scrape?

Comment: Do you think? - it is the product pages of www.europris.no